# Error while executing PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor

```
set serveroutput on;

begin
for rec in (select * from emp) loop
  insert into emp (stars) values (rpad(' ', salary/1000, '*'));
end loop;
end;
/
```

Returns the following errors:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 45:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I want to add in the `stars` column of the `emp` table (same as `employees`), a string of asterisks one for each 1000 in salary.

Could someone please explain what the error is about. Thanks

Comment: You don't need a cursor to do this, just a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just spotted my mistake.

```
update emp set stars = rpad('*', salary/1000, '*');
```

is the right statement.